# PDPageContentStream.AppendMode cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

When I  try to instantiate the content stream like below I get the deprecated message.

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true);
```

When I change the code as mentioned from the [release notes](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html) as

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = PDPageContentStream(originalDoc, page1, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode, true, true);
```

I get an Error as PDPageContentStream.AppendMode cannot be resolved to a variable. Could anyone suggest any workaround. I am using pdfbox2.0.9 version

Answer (score 3):

You aren't specifying which constant to use, you have 3 options:
`APPEND`, `OVERWRITE` or `PREPEND`.
So if you want to append, change your code to

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = PDPageContentStream(originalDoc, page1, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
```

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.html